# embed OSM and Google Imagery in a WebGIS

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap, google-maps

I've tried to add a google "hybrid" layer as a base map layer in a webGIS...

The script is in js and is like this :

(I only post this part of the code)

```
        {
            _layer:new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
                "OpenSreetMap",
                "",{
                    icon:'images/earth.png',
                    projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    fractionalZoom:false,
                    isBaseLayer:true,
                    maxExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34")

                })
        },
        {
            _layer:new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Hybrid",
                "",{
                    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                    icon:'images/earth.png'                     
                    projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                    fractionalZoom:false,
                    isBaseLayer:true,
                    maxExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds.fromString("-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34")

                })
        },
```

...

For the OSM part, it works perfectly, but not for the Google part...

Would you have some clue about that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
 map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
     projection: "EPSG:900913",
     displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
     allOverlays: true
 });

var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("osmLayer");
 var googleStr = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("googleStr", { numZoomLevels: 20, visibility: false });
 var googleHyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("googleHyb", { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20, visibility: false });
 var googleSat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("googleSat", { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 20, visibility: false });
 map.addLayers([osmLayer, googleStr, googleHyb, googleSat]);
```